# java - Can't export an image into a runnable jar file

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, export

I am attempting to export a program that has to do with images. When I export said project it gives me an IllegalArgumentException where the input is null. I have looked all over for the answer but each one doesn't seem to work with my code:

```
package dev.ttt;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Assets {

    public static BufferedImage x, o;

        public static void init() { //Loads the X and O images

            System.out.println("Loading Assets...");

            x = loadImage("/images/x.png");

            o = loadImage("/images/o.png");

            System.out.println("Assets loaded.");

       }

       public static void sayLoad(String path) { //Prints the image path to the console
           System.out.println("Loading " + path);
       }

    public static BufferedImage loadImage(String path) {
        try {
            sayLoad(path); //Prints the image path to the console
            return ImageIO.read(Assets.class.getResourceAsStream(path));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Any idea how to resolve this? It works fine in Eclipse, but not in a jar.

EDIT:

The output from java -jar "myjar.jar":

```
Initializing window...
Size: 330 330
Initializing Canvas...
Initialization complete.
Starting Thread...
Thread Started.
Initializing Game...
Loading Assets...
Loading /images/x.png
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
    at dev.ttt.Assets.loadImage(Assets.java:31)
    at dev.ttt.Assets.init(Assets.java:16)
    at dev.ttt.GameLoop.gameInit(GameLoop.java:81)
    at dev.ttt.GameLoop.run(GameLoop.java:129)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

EDIT 2:

```
55 Sun Sep 24 17:47:30 EDT 2017 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
1308 Sat Sep 23 20:18:30 EDT 2017 dev/ttt/WinDetection.class
3719 Sat Sep 23 20:18:30 EDT 2017 dev/ttt/GameLoop.class
2347 Sun Sep 24 17:47:14 EDT 2017 dev/ttt/Game.class
1451 Sun Sep 24 17:47:14 EDT 2017 dev/ttt/Assets.class
503 Sat Sep 23 20:18:30 EDT 2017 dev/ttt/Launcher.class
2874 Sat Sep 23 20:18:30 EDT 2017 dev/ttt/ai/AI.class
456 Sat Sep 23 20:18:30 EDT 2017 dev/ttt/player/Player.class
2875 Sat Sep 23 20:18:30 EDT 2017 dev/ttt/player/MouseInput.class
1010 Sun Sep 24 12:09:46 EDT 2017 images/O.png
1034 Sun Sep 24 12:09:46 EDT 2017 images/X.png
310 Thu Sep 21 12:22:30 EDT 2017 .checkstyle
385 Thu Sep 21 12:26:28 EDT 2017 .project
343 Sat Sep 23 21:03:18 EDT 2017 .classpath
```

Comment: Please list the output from "jar tvf your.jar"

Comment: @OP re edit: ThorbjørnRavnAndersen didn't ask for stacktrace (although this also can be useful so don't remove it), but about JAR file structure which can be obtained via `jar tvf your.jar` command (more info at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/view.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your jar file needs to have the "/images/x.png" and "/images/o.png" entries for this to work (so they are on the class path).  It doesn't for some reason.

In general, the first thing to look for in this situation is if the world is actually like you think it is.  Looking inside the jar with `jar tvf my.jar` can reveal a lot!

Comment: That makes sence but... i have no idea how to run that, I put it into my cmd prompt and it said: 'jar' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Just figured it out, had to update my path variable!

Comment: Finally figured it out... silliest mistake on my part.. i forgot to capitalize my file paths, using the jar tvf my.jar helped me see that. Thak you for the help!

Answer (score -1):

Looks like your application can't find images which you specify in relative path. Try to place your images in the folder *images* near your jar file.

Comment: While your solution would work for posted code, it is not what OP asked for. One of main reasons to create JARs is to let it wrap all things needed by application (like images/icons). Putting them outside of JAR is step back from preferred solution.